# Convert code of a User Control from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have this code for a custom User Control in VB.NET:

[Link To Code](http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/creating-a-real-transparent-label-in-vb-net.html#comment-21274)

And i use this site for converting it to C#:

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

And the result after Converting is :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class TransparentLabel {

public TransparentLabel() {
    //  This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent();
    //  Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    //  Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    RF = new RectangleF(0, 0, base.Width, base.Height);
    LabelForeColorBrush = new SolidBrush(base.ForeColor);
}

private StringFormat sFormat;

private RectangleF RF;

private SolidBrush LabelForeColorBrush = null;

private void UpdateText() {
    try {
        sFormat = new StringFormat();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        // With...
        switch (TextAlignment) {
            case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.TopLeft:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.TopRight:
                sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                break;
        }
        sFormat.FormatFlags = StringDirection;
        ResizeControl();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

private void ResizeControl() {
    RF.Size = new Size(base.Size);
    Invalidate();
}

private StringFormatFlags _StringDirection = (StringFormatFlags.NoClip < Description("The Direction of the Text."));

public StringFormatFlags StringDirection {
    get {
        return _StringDirection;
    }
    set {
        _StringDirection = value;
        UpdateText;
    }
}

private System.Drawing.ContentAlignment _TextAlignment = (ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter < Description("The Text Alignment that will appear on this control."));

public System.Drawing.ContentAlignment TextAlignment {
    get {
        return _TextAlignment;
    }
    set {
        _TextAlignment = value;
        UpdateText();
    }
}

public override System.Drawing.Color ForeColor {
    get {
        return base.ForeColor;
    }
    set {
        base.ForeColor = value;
        LabelForeColorBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
    }
}

private string _Labeltext = ("TransparentLabel" < Description("The text to be displayed in supports with real transparency."));

public string LabelText {
    get {
        return _Labeltext;
    }
    set {
        _Labeltext = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(false)]
public override System.Drawing.Color BackColor {
    get {
        return base.BackColor;
    }
    set {
        base.BackColor = value;
    }
}

protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle = (cp.ExStyle | 32);
        return cp;
    }
}

protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {
    try {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        //  draw the text on the control
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LabelText, base.Font, LabelForeColorBrush, RF, sFormat);
        //  MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

private void TransparentLabel_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    ResizeControl();
}
}
```

But this code hast errors.one of them is For `InitializeComponent()` and for base key word.
How should i do convert it?

Comment: I think you need to inherit from `Form`.Try: `TransparentLabel :Form`

Comment: @LewsTherin For a _control_? That would be inherit from `UserControl`.

Comment: `InitializeComponent` is problematic because it doesn't exist; this class should have a designer part which would have been automatically created by VS, if you're using VS, when creating a new user control.

Comment: @GrantThomas UserControl is only found in WPF isn't it?

Comment: Oh.. @Saman ignore everything I said.

Comment: @GrantThomas No,winforms has it too,but you right we should use new User Control but the problem is : [EditorBrowsable(false)].

Comment: Ok,if you are not lazy,please do that for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the conversion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.ComponentModel;

/// <summary>
/// This Program Created by: SourceHints.com
/// Nolan F. Sunico - SourceHints Administrator
/// You are free to use or modify this code
/// but please visit our website for new articles
/// </summary>
/// <DateCreated>November 30, 2011</DateCreated>
/// <TimeCreated>3:43 PM</TimeCreated>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public partial class TransparentLabel
{
    public TransparentLabel()
    {

        // This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        RF = new RectangleF(0, 0, base.Width, base.Height);
        LabelForeColorBrush = new SolidBrush(base.ForeColor);
    }
#region Private
    private StringFormat sFormat;
    private RectangleF RF;
    private SolidBrush LabelForeColorBrush = null;
#endregion
#region Subroutines
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates Text of this control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void UpdateText()
    {
        try
        {
            sFormat = new StringFormat();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
//INSTANT C# NOTE: The following VB 'Select Case' included either a non-ordinal switch expression or non-ordinal, range-type, or non-constant 'Case' expressions and was converted to C# 'if-else' logic:
//              Select Case TextAlignment
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
            if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.BottomCenter)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.BottomLeft)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.BottomRight
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.BottomRight)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.MiddleRight)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.TopCenter
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.TopCenter)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.TopLeft
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.TopLeft)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            }
//ORIGINAL LINE: Case ContentAlignment.TopRight
            else if (TextAlignment == ContentAlignment.TopRight)
            {
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            sFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            }
            sFormat.FormatFlags = StringDirection;
            ResizeControl();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Resizes Transparent Label Control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void ResizeControl()
    {
        RF.Size = new Size(base.Size);
        Invalidate();
    }
#endregion
#region Properties
    private StringFormatFlags _StringDirection = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
    [Description("The Direction of the Text."), DefaultValue(StringFormatFlags.NoClip)]
    public StringFormatFlags StringDirection
    {
        get
        {
            return _StringDirection;
        }
        set
        {
            _StringDirection = value;
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

    private System.Drawing.ContentAlignment _TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    [Description("The Text Alignment that will appear on this control."), DefaultValue(ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter)]
    public System.Drawing.ContentAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextAlignment;
        }
        set
        {
            _TextAlignment = value;
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

#endregion
#region Overrides
    public override System.Drawing.Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ForeColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ForeColor = value;
            LabelForeColorBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The text to be displayed in supports with real transparency.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private string _Labeltext = "TransparentLabel";
    [Description("The text to be displayed in supports with real transparency."), Category("Text"), DefaultValue("TransparentLabel")]
    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return _Labeltext;
        }
        set
        {
            _Labeltext = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(false)]
    public override System.Drawing.Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = value;
        }
    }
    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            // draw the text on the control
            e.Graphics.DrawString(LabelText, base.Font, LabelForeColorBrush, RF, sFormat);
            // MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
#endregion
    private void TransparentLabel_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ResizeControl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but how should i use it?and EditorBrowsable(false) is wrong.

Comment: Try to use this converter http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_CSharp.html and convert the entire VB Code from the link you provided.

Comment: This application convert entire solution perfectly,but in the part that you convert it too,solution has some errors.

Comment: @AppDeveloper this application has demo version for free.